# Enable search for a Projection with custom Content Items

Tags: search, orchardcms

I've created a custom content item. I also have a projection which filters the content items (e.g. on a tag or something else).

I've installed the Modules: Search, Indexing and Lucene but when I search for an article I don't seem to find any of my custom Content Items.

How can this be done?

I'm using Orchard 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.
After installing search the "Index this content type for search" was not directly visible on my custom Content Item.
The field appeared when I added another Field to my Content Item and saved it.
That is the reason I could not find or select it :-)